# increase boarder when mouse hover

Tags: css

How can I get my boarder to increase in size when the mouse hovers over this css rule.

```
.script_list > div:first-child,
.script_list > div.ui-sortable-helper {
  border-width: 1px;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply with the `:hover` suffix as such :

```
.script_list > div:first-child:hover,
.script_list > div.ui-sortable-helper:hover {
  border-width: 2px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a basic [working example.](http://jsfiddle.net/4zuzj/)

Pretty simple with basic CSS, using the `:hover` state. Use the `box-sizing` property to ensure your overall box size (and subsequently your layout) doesn't get effected, if that isn't the desired effect.

**CSS**

```
.frame {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;

    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
}

.frame:hover {
    border-width: 10px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="frame"></div>
```

Comment: actually, the `box-sizing` part is critical if you want to maintain the layout.

Comment: Indeed @Harsh, that's a better way to phrase that.